# For loop not working stating the endpoint is a float

Tags: python, loops

So for context, I'm working on a program that requires the Guass formula. It's used to find for example, 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1, or, 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1.

The formula is (n*(n + 1))/2,
I tried to incorporate this into a for loop, but I'm getting an error stating:

"'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

This is my code:

```
# Defining Variables #
print("Give me a start")
x = int(input())
print("Give me a delta")
y = int(input())
print("Give me an amount of rows")
z = int(input())
archive_list = []
f = z + 1
stop = z*f
final_stop = stop/2

# Main Logic #

for loop in range(1,final_stop,1):
    print("hi")
```

I would appreciate a response on why it wasn't working as well as a fixed code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `stop/2` is a floating-point number, so `final_stop` is a `float`, but `float`s can't be used as "endpoints" is `range`, only `int`egers are allowed.

Comment: Use stop//2 which will be int

Answer (score 1):

As @ForceBru noted in his excellent comment, the problem is that the endpoint `final_stop` is a float, instead of an int.
The reason is because when computing it you used a single / instead of double.
If you replace
`final_stop = stop/2`
with
`final_stop = stop//2`,
then it should work fine.

Comment: That is great. If you appreciate this answer and want to accept and upvote it, that would be really SWEET!